How to make in MUI Autocomplete component two tabs to switch states of one list
How can I make it possible to switch between list states inside Autocomplete MUI. The category list is common for all, but it has two states - enabled or excluded. If a value is selected in one of the states, it is not available for selection in the other state. On the layout it looks like this
Here is my codesanbox. I don't understand how to make the toggle buttons appear inside autocomplete, and the selected values for both statuses are shown at the same time
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/mutable-butterfly-mt57g9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.js%3A20%2C13
